# SAPUI5- Hide button in a listitem when it is clicked

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to hide a button of a particular item on the list? Lets say I have a list with swipedContent which contains a button with id: "actionButton". I want to hide "actionButton" when it is clicked.

Code:

```
new sap.m.List("list", {

backgroundDesign : "Transparent",
        mode : sap.ui.Device.system.phone ? sap.m.ListMode.None
                : sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelectMaster,
        itemPress : [ oController.handleListSelect, oController ],
        swipeContent : new sap.m.Button({
            id: "actionButton",
            text : "Actions",
            type : "Accept",
            press : [ oController.onPress, oController ]
            })
    })
```

EDIT:

```
onPress: function(e){

    var list = this.getView().byId("list");
    var swipedItem = list.getSwipedItem();
    //Below code destroys swipeContent from ALL THE ITEMS in the list which I don't want
    list.destroySwipeContent();
    //And this doesnot work
    swipedItem.destroySwipeContent();

}
```

If I use:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("actionButton").setVisible(false);
```

It will hide the buttons from all the items. But I want it to hide for that particular item. Is there a way?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: did you try sap.ui.getCore().byId("#actionButton").setVisible(false); I think your selector does not work! if its an ID, use # upfront.

Comment: also $(#'button).hide() would solve your issue if you put it in the right function ... opposite is .show()

Comment: Both of the above solutions not working.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've written, I understand that you want the action button to disappear once you've pressed it. This happens automatically already - see the [Explored example for the Sample: List - Swipe](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListSwipe/preview) (you can set Chrome to emulate a phone so you can test the swipe; I'd also suggest you modify the sample List.controller.js on the fly so that it doesn't remove the item (the default action for this sample):

```
handleReject: function (evt) {
    var oList = evt.getSource().getParent();
    // Next line commented out on purpose, for testing
    // oList.removeAggregation("items", oList.getSwipedItem());
    oList.swipeOut();
}
```

so you can see the result.

Comment: The problem with the above code is it will only hide the button once. Again if I swipe on the item the button appears. What I want is to permanently hide the button on clicking it so that when next time I swipe on that particular item, the button should not appear.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This requirement wasn't obvious from your original question. Looking at the sample code I linked to in my answer, you could perhaps remove the swipeContent content for the specific list item, once the button was clicked.

Comment: That is exactly what I want, " removing the swipeContent content for the specific list item once the button is clicked". But how to destroySwipeContent for a particular item, can you show me in terms of code?

Comment: I added my "onPress" function in the question.